# sorting a list without using sort/remove functions

Tags: list, sorting, for-loop, append

I'm trying to sort a list for int type, so that the first element is the lowest and the last is the highest value.
I can't use sort function or remove/del.
only simple methods like for, while and or /append and so on.

I tried using for loop but don't know what to do exactly.

thank you for your help

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the wonderful world of algorithms. If you were playing a card game, and had 10 cards in your hand and wanted to sort them. How would you do it? Can you describe what you would do in words? Then we can turn this description into a more formal algorithm.

Comment: Yes, just simulate the `real life` scenario, like Stef suggested.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.